# Xcode отключение сохранения проекта при последующем его открытии

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Как отключить функцию сохранения проекта ,чтобы Xcode при следующем открытии открывал мне новый этот же проект ,но с нуля ,а не тот же с моими изменениями.

Answer (score 0):

Никак.

Лично я очень рекомендую использовать Git и программу SourceTree. В ней вы можете мгновенно и наглядно откатить ваши изменения.